# What's the Distance Distribution for Points within the Poisson-Voronoi Tessellation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I would like to ask a question about the distance distribution (from the origin/core to any location within its Poisson-Voronoi Tessellation).

We read some about Tessellations and find there is description of the contact density function, the intersection length distribution, etc.
But what is the distance distribution for any point(location) within the voronoi tessellation to the origin?

Could you tell where to find it or give me some tips?

Thanks in advance. Comments and discussions are welcome if I didn't state clearly.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly what you're asking. You have a set of Poisson-distributed points, upon which a Voronoi tesselation is constructed. Is the question: What is the probability density function for the distance between a point selected uniformly & randomly from within a Voronoi cell, and the seed point which defines that cell? If so, I think this has an analytical solution.

Comment: I am sorry i did not provide it clearly. For the voronoi where the origin o is contained, the distance distribution of the length "from any random point within this voronoi to the origin". I think the question is equal to:the distance any point within one voronoi (not all points within the planar) to the nearest PPP point? Is contact distance distribution describes this?  Thanks.

Comment: What is a "contact density function"?  Google isn't helping with that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, "contact distribution function".

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I interpret the intended meaning of this question:

Suppose we have a two-dimensional (people usually mean 2D when they talk about Voronoi tessellations, although they can exist in any number of dimensions) Poisson Voronoi tessellation with a density $\rho$ of seed points. To each seed point is associated a cell. If we select a point uniformly and at random from within a given seed point's cell, what is the probability density function (pdf) for the distance between the random point and that cell's seed point?

Clearly, each cell has its own size and shape, and therefore its own unique distance pdf. What we really want is an average, generic pdf, averaged over all such cells. So we instead imagine picking a random point $p$ uniformly from anywhere in the whole tessellation (which we'll take to be arbitrarily large to avoid edge effects), and then determine the distance to the seed of whatever cell $p$ happens to land in.

However, by the definition of a Voronoi tessellation this is entirely equivalent to simply finding the pdf of the distance between $p$ and the nearest seed point... also known as the [nearest-neighbor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

Without loss of generality, take the point $p$ to be the origin. We imagine surrounding the origin with a finite circle of radius $R$ (which we'll later take to infinity) containing $N = \pi R^2 \rho$ seed points, for a density of $\rho$ within the circle. The cumulative distribution function (cdf) of the distance $r$ between each independently-selected seed point and the origin is given by
$$
F(r) = r^2 / R^2 \quad \text{for $0<r<R$.}
$$
Then the associated pdf is
$$
f(r) = F'(r) = 2r/R^2 \quad \text{for $0<r<R$.}
$$

What we want is the pdf for the distance to the origin of the nearest of these $N$ points. This is the $k = 1$ [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of these $N$ samples, and its pdf is given by (see link):
$$
f_1(r) = N {\left(1 - \frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)}^{N-1} \frac{2r}{R^2}\, .
$$
If we use the fact that $R^2 = N / \pi\rho$, this becomes:
$$
f_1(r) = 2\pi\,\rho\, r {\left(1 - \frac{\pi\rho r^2}{N}\right)}^{N-1}\, .
$$
Finally, we take the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$, since this is an "arbitrarily-large" tesselation, to arrive at the answer to the original question:
$$
f_1(r) \rightarrow 2\pi\rho\,  r\, \mathrm{e}^{- \pi \rho r^2}\, .
$$

All this assuming I've interpreted the question correctly. By the way, if you have access to a university or other technical library, the standard reference for all things Voronoi is [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471986356) book by Okabe, et al.

Comment: Thanks John for elaboration. I am sorry I do not clear know what you say "seed" point. Does it the origin o of a PPP $\Phi(\rho)$? or any point $x\in \Phi(\rho)$, since you say " this is entirely equivalent to simply finding the pdf of the distance between pp and **the nearest seed point**". It seems you provide the PDF for random points within the voronoi $t \notin \Phi(\rho)$. What I am really need is:

Comment: What I am really need is(I am sorry i did not provide it clearly): For the voronoi where the origin o is contained, the distance distribution of the length "from any random point within **this** voronoi  to the origin". I think the question is equal to:the distance any point within one voronoi (not all points within the planar) to the nearest PPP point?  Is contact distance distribution  describes this?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean by "a PPP". Look at [the wikipedia entry on Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). The "seed points" are the points that define the tessellation, i.e. the set of points it is built around. Each "seed point" has a Voronoi cell around it.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking better: Given a statistically homogeneous Poisson Voronoi tessellation in the plane, the origin $O$ will fall in some particular Voronoi cell $C$. What is the pdf of distances between $O$ and a point selected randomly and uniformly from $C$? Since all points in such a homogeneous tessellation are statistically equivalent, the origin is just as likely to reside anywhere in the cell with respect to $C$'s seed point. (cont'd...)

Comment: Thus, this question is equivalent to: Given two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ selected independently, randomly, and uniformly from within the same randomly-selected Voronoi cell $C$, what is the pdf for the distance $|p_1 - p_2|$ between them? I think this is a much harder problem than the one I answered above, and it may or may not have an analytical solution. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: Dear John, Do you interpret the distance as two random points within a randomly selected Voronoi cell? In fact, I mean One is a random point within the voronoi, the other endpoint is the nearest seed/site point (it must located within the same voronoi cell). It seems the contact distribution function presents some cased with different $d$. Some ref can be found by searching "contact distribution functions tessellation" on google. Can you please help to affirm this, Thank:)

Comment: I finally found a reference for the contact distribution... and it turned out to be in the supplementary materials for [one of my own papers](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.77.144106)! I had simply forgotten it. I quote myself from that reference: "The linear contact distribution function $H(x)$ is defined as the probability that two points a distance $x$ apart lie in different grains."

Comment: Anyway, you say: "I mean One is a random point within the voronoi, the other endpoint is the nearest seed/site point" If that is really what you mean, then the pdf of the resulting random distance is indeed given by my answer above. I don't think you need the contact distribution to get at this answer.